# Falla al hacer update con JPA persistence (JAVA)

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

Puedo guardar y eliminar registros, pero a la hora de actualizar no se realiza el cambio.

primero llamo mi objeto de la clase atleta con atletaJpa.findAtleta(id), luego seteo el objeto con el dato a cambiar y llamo a la persistencia para guardar el cambio

```
    private void btnActualizarVisorAtletaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    
    int fila = tablaVisorAtleta.getSelectedRow();
    
    Object rut =  tablaVisorAtleta.getValueAt(fila, 0);
    
   
    
    NbjsmAtleta atleta = controladoraLogica.traerAtleta(rut);
    

    atleta.setRutAtleta(txtrutVisorAtleta.getText());

    controladoraLogica.editarAtleta(atleta);

    filtrar();
    
    
}
```

En el Output tengo lo siguiente:

> [EL Info]: 2023-12-09 22:16:46.834--ServerSession(967064722)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.12.v20230209-e5c4074ef3
> dic 09, 2023 10:16:52 P. M. com.mycompany.gestiontikets.persistencia.ControladoraPersistencia editarAtleta
> SEVERE: null
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.mycompany.gestiontikets.logica.NbjsmAtleta.getIdEspecialidadatleta()" because "persistentNbjsmAtleta" is null
> at com.mycompany.gestiontikets.persistencia.NbjsmAtletaJpaController.edit(NbjsmAtletaJpaController.java:108)
> at com.mycompany.gestiontikets.persistencia.ControladoraPersistencia.editarAtleta(ControladoraPersistencia.java:167)
> at com.mycompany.gestiontikets.logica.ControladoraLogica.editarAtleta(ControladoraLogica.java:287)
> at com.mycompany.gestiontikets.igu.I_ModificarAtleta.btnActualizarVisorAtletaActionPerformed(I_ModificarAtleta.java:323)
> at com.mycompany.gestiontikets.igu.I_ModificarAtleta$2.actionPerformed(I_ModificarAtleta.java:95)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2314)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:407)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6620)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3398)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6385)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4995)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4827)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4827)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:775)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:98)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:747)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:744)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

Por ultimo las clases implicadas (atributos), las cuales fueron importadas a través de EntityClass from Database son las siguientes:

Clase Atleta:

```
public class NbjsmAtleta implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "rut_atleta")
private String rutAtleta;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "nombre_atleta")
private String nombreAtleta;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "fec_nac_atleta")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date fecNacAtleta;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "estado_atleta")
private String estadoAtleta;
@Column(name = "apellido_paterno_atleta")
private String apellidoPaternoAtleta;
@Column(name = "apellido_materno_atleta")
private String apellidoMaternoAtleta;
@OneToMany( mappedBy = "idAtletaeventoatleta")
private Collection<NbjsmEventoAtleta> nbjsmEventoAtletaCollection;
@JoinColumn(name = "idEspecialidad_atleta", referencedColumnName = "ID_especialidad")
@ManyToOne(optional = false )
private NbjsmEspecialidad idEspecialidadatleta;
@JoinColumn(name = "idCiudad_atleta", referencedColumnName = "ID_ciudad")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private NbjsmCiudad idCiudadatleta;
```

Clase Ciudad:

```
public class NbjsmCiudad implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ID_ciudad")
private Integer iDciudad;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "nombre_ciudad")
private String nombreCiudad;
@OneToMany( mappedBy = "idCiudadevento")
private Collection<NbjsmEvento> nbjsmEventoCollection;
@OneToMany( mappedBy = "idCiudadatleta",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Collection<NbjsmAtleta> nbjsmAtletaCollection;
```

Clase Especialidad:

```
public class NbjsmEspecialidad implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ID_especialidad")
private Integer iDespecialidad;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "nombre_especialidad")
private String nombreEspecialidad;
@OneToMany( mappedBy = "idEspecialidadatleta",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Collection<NbjsmAtleta> nbjsmAtletaCollection;
```

Por ultimo dejo una imagen del diagrama relacional:

[image: Modelo relacional sistema]

**He buscado mucho de como resolver esto y aun nada pero creo que el problema es como relaciono las tablas a traves de CascadeType.
Espero que puedan orientarme y muchas gracias c:**